# Enabling OnBoard Lan hangs Windows 7 at startup screen

Tags: windows-7, networking, freeze, boot

Im having windows7 32 bit, it just happened out of sudden my system hanged, I forcibly cut off the power and rebooted. At the startup screen where the four balls appear forming windows, my system hanged(everytime thereafter).

I tried to tweak some settings in the BIOS and found that switching off the ON BOARD LAN clears the problem. This even deprives me off from any internet activity. I tried to find topics with similar problems, but to no avail.

I have live-booted with Ubuntu to make sure that my on-board LAN hardware is OK. Ubuntu has no problems, it ran flawlessly.

- I have tried taking out the ethernet cable and rebooting.
- Tried to shut down the CPU, taken off the power cable and tried to press the power button for about 10min to make sure the chips in the CPU are completely discharged.
- neither Safe Mode nor Safe Mode With Networking works
  both hang at the point when CLASSPNP.sys driver is loaded
- After all I reinstalled a fresh copy of windows 7.

Its almost 5 days of trying to restore my windows 7 back to normal still my computer crashes at the startup screen.

Kindly help me. Your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does the clean install crash too?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a clean install there are a few things you could try.

Try entering the safe mode by hitting F8 during system boot (see [Boot Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsag/p/advanced-boot-options.htm) for more). Does the system boot? If yes then reboot it and enter the safe mode again, this time select the option with networking. Does the system boot too?

When this works press `<Windows Key>+<r>`, enter `devmgmt.msc` and hit `<Enter>`. Does any item in the list have a yellow question mark next to it?

Comment: as i have already mentioned there was no luck with safe mode nor with any other options under Boot Options.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that line for some reason. Can you try to do what it says in the last post on that page: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/my-computer-freezes-during-loading-classpnpsys/5f3a3318-3fe6-4563-96bb-3b3165448f43

Comment: that even does not work..
I guess I have to do all the networking stuff in Ubuntu, and have to work offline with windows :(